# Computing integration $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)\sin(x)}{x} dx$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I can't seem to find this problem on Math.SE, so sorry if it actually exists.

I want to evaluate $I(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log(ax)\sin x}{x} dx$. Then I separated it into two integrals $I(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log(a)\sin x}{x} + \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)\sin x}{x}$. The first term is constant and evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{2}\log a$, and the second term is where I am struggling with, it's equal to $I(1)$.

I also tried using differentiation under the integral sign, but it gives the same result, as I get $I'(a) = \frac{\pi}{2a}$, and I can't find the constant.

I also tried putting the variable inside $\sin(x)$, so $J(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log x \sin(ax)}{x}$, but $I'(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \log x \cos(ax) dx$ is divergent.

WolframAlpha gives something about $\pi\gamma$, so I am wondering where that comes from.

Thanks!

Comment: Try here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941888/calculate-int-0-infty-frac-sinx-logxx-mathrm-dx?noredirect=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053019/integral-with-euler-mascheroni-constant?noredirect=1.

Comment: If you are looking for a hint, try looking at Laplace transforms for a quick method to solve this.

Comment: $$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)\sin(x)}{x} dx=\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}\Im\int_0^{\infty} e^{ix}x^{1-\epsilon}dx=\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\bigg|_{\epsilon=0}\Im I_\epsilon$$
Making a turn in the complex plane (what is equivalent to the change $x=te^\frac{\pi i}{2}$; integral along a quarter-circle $\to 0$ as the radius $\to\infty$)
$$I_\epsilon=e^\frac{\pi i\epsilon}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{\epsilon-1}dt\,\Rightarrow\, \Im I_\epsilon =\sin\frac{\pi \epsilon}{2}\Gamma(\epsilon)=\frac{\sin\frac{\pi \epsilon}{2}}{\epsilon}\Gamma(1+\epsilon)$$

Comment: $$\Gamma(1+\epsilon)=1-\gamma\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2); \quad\frac{\sin\frac{\pi\epsilon}{2}}{\epsilon}=\frac{\pi}{2}+O(\epsilon^2)$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. @Svyatoslav I am not too familiar with complex analysis, though I will get some paper and see if the math makes sense haha. @ HackR I don't know laplace transformation. This is from an integration competition (essentially integration bee...) and laplace transform is out of syllabus too

Answer (score 2):

By using robjohn's answer [Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3803434/148155) then one can determine that
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x) \, \sin(b x)}{x} \, dx = - \frac{\pi}{2} \, \text{sgn}(b) \, (\ln|b| - \gamma). $$
As seen by the basis of the proposed problem the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(a x) \, \sin(b x)}{x} \, dx $$
then follows as:
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(a x) \, \sin(b x)}{x} \, dx \\
&= \ln(a) \, \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(b x)}{x} \, dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x) \, \sin(b x)}{x} \, dx \\
&= \ln(a) \, \frac{\pi}{2} \, \text{sgn}(b) - \frac{\pi}{2} \, \text{sgn}(b) \, ( \ln|b| + \gamma) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \, \text{sgn}(b) \, \ln\left(\frac{a}{|b|} \, e^{-\gamma}\right). 
\end{align}
Here, $\text{sgn}(x)$ is the sign of $x$ and is $+1$ for $x>0$ and $-1$ otherwise.

Comment: Nice answer, I like it very much. Congratulations ! I have already upvoted you.